# Spring boot: Database connection not closing properly

Tags: sql-server, spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I'm executing queries periodically (by a scheduler) using my Spring Boot application

**application.properties**

```
src_mssqlserver_url=jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.0.1;databaseName=Test;
src_mssqlserver_username=tester
src_mssqlserver_password=tester1
src_mssqlserver_driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

**Datasource and JdbcTemplate Bean**

```
@Primary
    @Bean(name = "src_mssqlserver")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.ds_mssqlserver")
    public DataSource srcDataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("src_mssqlserver_driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("src_mssqlserver_url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("src_mssqlserver_username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("src_mssqlserver_password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "srcJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate srcJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("src_mssqlserver") DataSource dsSrcSqlServer) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dsSrcSqlServer);
    }
```

**Usage: This method is called from a scheduler with list of items to process (normally 1000 records), this process runs in an hour once.**

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("srcJdbcTemplate")
private JdbcTemplate srcJdbcTemplate;

public void batchInsertUsers(final List<User> users) {
        String queryInsert = "INSERT INTO [User] ([Name]"
                + "     , [Created_Date]"
                + "     , [Notes])"
                + " VALUES (?, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), ?)";

        srcJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(queryInsert, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
            @Override
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                User user = users.get(i);

                ps.setString(1, user.getName());
                ps.setString(2, user.getNotes());
            }

            @Override
            public int getBatchSize() {
                return sites.size();
            }
        });
```

I'm getting warnings from database administrator that my code keeping too much connections open. Please share some standard and workable way to handle such situation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

DriverManagerDataSource is NOT meant for production, it opens and closes a connection each time it needs one.

Use a connection pool like c3p0DataSource.